# JProfiler not working in IntelliJ 12 (JProfiler executable is null)

Tags: intellij-idea, jprofiler

I'm trying to profile my Android app. I installed the JProfiler plugin through

> IntelliJ IDEA --> Preferences --> Plugins

Here's a screenshot of the plugin description:

[image: JProfiler plugin description]

When I try to run the profiler nothing happens and I get this message saying that the JProfiler executable is null:

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed JProfiler (not just the plugin)?

Comment: I assumed the plugin came with a JProfiler install. It's a separate install?

Comment: Yes, the plugin integrates a JProfiler installation with the IDEA installation.

Answer (score 11):

You need to set or re-set the JProfiler executable. Do the following:

- Select "Edit Configurations" from the "Run" drop down menu
- Select "Application" under "Defaults" in the dialog box (or any existing run configuration)
- Select the "Startup/Connection" tab
- Select "JProfiler" in the list
- Click on the "Select JProfiler Executable" button
- Choose the JProfiler executable, which is

> - [JProfiler installation directory]\bin\jprofiler.exe on Windows
> - [JProfiler installation directory]/bin/jprofiler on Linux/Unix
> - [JProfiler installation directory]/bin/macos/jprofiler.sh on Mac OS X

Comment: After starting JProfiler on IntelliJ 12, it may not find the correct JVM profiling port. Look for it in JProfiler's output window (under "JProfiler> Listening on port: xxxx"). Get xxx and paste it into JProfiler's dialog that should be in the background.

Answer (score 9):

You have to install JProfiler first, you can download it [here](http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files).

Comment: I did install it. I'm still having the same problem. FYI, I skipped the "integrate IDE" step because I could not locate the "plugins" folder it was specifically looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have JProfiler 7.2.2 (or newer) which integrates with IntelliJ IDEA 12 
http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/changelog.html#7.2.2

To start, in a file browser check if you have the plugins folder, if not create it, so it looks like this

```
C:\Users\[username]\.IntelliJIdea12\config\plugins
```

If running IntelliJ IDEA 12, close it.

Inside JProfiler go to

```
Session -> IDE Integrations
```

And choose `IntelliJ IDEA 12.x` and click `Proceed` button

Choose your `.IntelliJIdea12` folder

```
C:\Users\[username]\.IntelliJIdea12
```

And you're done, you should see a new button Next to `Run [class#method] with Coverage` that says `Profile [class#method]`